# Unexpected end of JSON input -> characters in MySQL DB

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I tried to get data from MySQL db and create table. Ajax code for build table:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'funcGetHyperActiveAccounts.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {server_id:serverId, date:date},
    success: function(data) {
        $("#LogAnalyserTableHyperactiveAccounts tbody tr").remove();
        data = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(data));

        let table = document.getElementById('LogAnalyserTableHyperactiveAccounts').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let row = table.insertRow(i);
            let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            let cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
            let cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
            let cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
            cell1.innerHTML = data[i][0];
            cell1.className = "d-none d-xl-table-cell text-end";
            cell2.innerHTML = data[i][1];
            cell2.className = "d-none d-xl-table-cell text-end";
            cell3.innerHTML = data[i][2];
            cell3.className = "d-none d-xl-table-cell text-start";
            cell4.innerHTML = data[i][3];
            cell4.className = "d-none d-xl-table-cell text-end";
            cell5.innerHTML = data[i][4];
            cell5.className = "d-none d-xl-table-cell text-start";
            cell6.innerHTML = data[i][5];
            cell6.className = "d-none d-xl-table-cell text-start";
            cell7.innerHTML = data[i][6];
            cell7.className = "d-none d-xl-table-cell text-end";
        }
    },
    complete: function() {
        tables--;
        IsTablesRenderDone(tables);
    }
});
```

and funcGetHyperActiveAccounts.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "../../api/db.php";
    include "../../api/api.php";

    function cmp($a, $b) {
        if ($a['messages'] == $b['messages']) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a['messages'] > $b['messages']) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    $result = GetLogAnalyserTableHyperactiveAccounts($db, $_POST['server_id'], $_POST['date']);

    if (empty($result)) {
        $array = array(0 => array("no data", "", "", "", "", "", ""));
    } else {
        uasort($result, 'cmp');
        $array = array();

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($result as $item) {
            $array[$i] = array($item['messages'], $item['login'], $item['group'], $item['ip'], $item['name'], $item['country'], $item['email']);
            $i++;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

It works normally. But in DB can be names of clients like Chinese or Russians that wasn't converted with CRM normally: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQiUp.png)

So because of this I got error

```
VM4444:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (index.php:447)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
```

We can't change data in DB and must return name exactly as in DB. But I can change setting or DB table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved next steps:

1. Checked that database, table and field COLLATE set to utf8_general_ci
2. I changed in PHP file - I know that name field can have characters

   ```
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($result as $item) {
       $array[$i] = array($item['messages'], $item['login'], $item['group'], $item['ip'], $item['name'], $item['country'], $item['email']);
       $i++;
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   $i = 0;
   foreach ($result as $item) {
       $array[$i] = array($item['messages'], $item['login'], $item['group'], $item['ip'], utf8_encode($item['name']), $item['country'], $item['email']);
       $i++;
   }
   ```
3. In JS must be

   ```
   data = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(data));
   ```

So it means that in PHO code I encoded an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8 and in JS decode them  back. Result:
[image: screenshot]

Links that helps me:

1. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error a few days ago and it was due that the url did not match with the real url of the resource. For instance:

I was calling http://localhost:5000/file.json and the resource was in http://localhost:5001/file.json

The error message was not very helpfull makes me think that it was due with an issue in the Json file but finally it was not

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Maybe you are in a similar situation that I was

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse() on a valid JSON will result in an error. Try to print the data and see

Comment: True. I tried to see data after parsing - before parsing data was null.